# JavaScript along with the HTML file is not running in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I have placed the HTML Resource files and java script files with the project files in my iphone application. My objective is to build an application which has UIWebview which loads when we tab on the app icon. The UIWebView should actually load the local html content that I have in the resource folder. I can see the HTMl content in the webview but its not running the Javascript..

Comment: Its not possible to comment or speculate without seeing some code.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: in the

[UIWebView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Her the actual problem comes with adding the files(javascript and css) in the project. while adding files following option should be clicked that showed in the following image.

[image: Files kike js,html and css]